# Add empty row after column that contains spefific text

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I have a large dataframe where I need to add an empty row after any instance where colA contains a colon.

To be honest I have absolutely no clue how to do this, my guess is that a function/ for loop needs to be written but I have had no luck...

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem? How does the data look which you are trying to manipulate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

You have dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"cola": ["a", "b", ":", "c", "d", ":", "e"]})
 # wherever you find : in column a you want to append new empty row
idx = [0] + (df[df.cola.str.match(':')].index +1).tolist()
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(idx)-1):
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df.iloc[idx[i]: idx[i+1]]],ignore_index=True)
    df1.loc[len(df1)] = ""
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df.iloc[idx[-1]: ]], ignore_index=True)
print(df1)
# df1 is your result dataframe also it handles the case where colon is present at the last row of dataframe

Resultant dataframe
cola
0   a
1   b
2   :
3   
4   c
5   d
6   :
7   
8   e
```